# Shell - Delete line if the line has only one column?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I delete the first column (string) if the line has only one string on the first column?

```
abc def geh
ijk
123 xyz 345
mno
```

**Expected output**

```
abc def geh
123 xyz 345
```

Comment: It's equivalent to "how do I delete a line if it doesn't contain a space", right? Or further, to "how do I only output lines that contain spaces?". If so, `grep ' '` will do the trick ([try it here](https://ideone.com/GEtDps))

Comment: @Aaron : This would keep lines which consist only of spaces. It is not clear from the OPs question, what he wants in this case.

Comment: @janasu :  make use of this command : `grep -E "[a-z] " abc.txt  >> new.txt`                                Note : i have used space after `"[a-z]  "`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of option are available. One of them could be this :

```
grep " " myfile.txt
```

The output corresponding of the expected result. This command filter just the line with at least one space.
This works if first string have no space at end, if not this one works too :

```
awk 'NF > 1' myfile.txt
```

Comment: This works when file doesn't have white space. Looks like my file has white space after the string and I am not getting the expected result. Is there any alternate way to delete a row with a single string?

Comment: yes let me update my answer

Answer (score 5):

A simple `awk` does the job without regex:

```sh
awk 'NF > 1' file

abc def geh
123 xyz 345
```

This will work for the cases when line has leading or trailing space or there are lines with just the white spaces.

Comment: The right tool for the job, but to be fair a basic `grep` solution isn't using regex either

Comment: Yes a `grep -F` won't be using regex